# Looking for out-of-place directories in an SVN working copy?

Tags: svn

An annoyance that I sometimes come across with SVN is the working copy getting corrupted by one of the .svn folders getting moved from its original location. It doesn't happen often if you're careful and use the proper tools for all moves and renames, but it still somehow happens from time to time.

First, does anyone know if there's a good way to catch the problem before a commit is even done? Cruise control usually catches the problem, but there are plenty of cases it wouldn't catch.

Second, is there a quick and easy way to check for out-of-place .svn folder if I suspect that there is one? I can definitely do it manually by deducing what directory is out of place based on the compiler errors or by diffing the working copy with another clean checkout. But, this seems like a problem that SVN can diagnose in a second by giving me a list of all directories whose parent directory in  the working copy doesn't match its parent directory in the repository. There there some way to have SVN give me a list like that?

Thanks.

Comment: Invest in a better mouse, folders doesn't move around by themselves, so most likely you're dragging them around when you just intend to move the mouse over the folder window.

Comment: My top suspect is Eclipse. I have Subclipse installed and I'm sure that I moved the offending folder inside Eclipse. I've done it plenty of times without any problems though so I'm not sure what was special about the move that messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `svn status` command can help with this.

For example, suppose that I have a directory `foo`, and in the repository it has subdirectories `bar` and `baz`.  And suppose that I move `baz` into `bar`, without telling SVN.  Then, I get:

```
$ svn status foo/
?      foo/bar/baz
!      foo/baz
```

The `?` for `foo/bar/baz` indicates that it exists in the local version but not in the repository -- more precisely, that it exists within the `foo/bar` directory on your local copy, but the SVN information in `foo/bar/.svn` has no record of it.  Similarly, the `!` for `foo/baz` indicates that it exists in the repository (or, more precisely, in the information in `foo/.svn`), but the actual file/directory in your local copy is missing.

Meanwhile, if the problem is just a `.svn` folder itself that's gone missing, that will show up like this:

```
$ svn status foo/
~      foo/quux
```

That means that `foo/.svn` says that there should be a `foo/quux`, and `foo/quux` exists, but there is no `foo/quux/.svn`.

Finally, if the problem is that a directory has a `.svn` that's pointing at somewhere else other than the subdirectory of its parent -- say you've done an `svn switch` on that directory -- then you'll get this:

```
$ svn status foo/
    S  foo/quuux
```

If you're in Windows and using TortoiseSVN, you can get the same information by right-clicking in the top-level directory, and selecting "TortoiseSVN -> Check for Modifications" from the pop-up menu.  Things that have been switched (i.e., the wrong `.svn` directory) will show up as "normal (s)" in their status.